# OpenCcpCoverage cannot find pdb files in Visual Studios 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-coverage

I'm trying to know the coverage of a cpp project, but i keep having a html exported with coverage of 0%, with

```
OpenCppCoverage.exe --sources "C:/WorkSpace/project" --excluded_sources "C:/Worksapce/project/libs" --quiet --cover_children -- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" dTests.dll /Platform:X64
```

But if I select the particular tests, I get the correct coverage, with

```
 OpenCppCoverage.exe --sources "C:/WorkSpace/project" --excluded_sources "C:/Worksapce/project/libs" --quiet --cover_children -- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" dTests.dll /Platform:X64 /Tests:"TestMethod1,TestMethod2"
```

Here a references for VSTest: 
VSTest.Console  [https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/jj155800.aspx]

So, I think it could be some kind of trouble with the way in that OpenCppCoverage look for the methods.. Any idea?